# Regression with percentage (%race/gender) as a predictor variable

Tags: regression, inference, econometrics, poisson-regression, percentage

I have data on  hospital admission rates for 5 years at zip code level.  I also have percentages on each of the 3 race categories, and percentages of gender for each of the 5 years at the zip code level. This data will be analysed using Poisson model to study the effect of race and gender on rates.

Can I make inferences about the difference in rates across years by gender (or race) when gender(or race) is measured in percentages?

Comment: You should make sure that you include controls for the baseline populations over time (though a five year time span shouldn’t be too large) as racial makeup of a zip code can change over time.

Comment: Thanks for your response Alex.  Could you please elaborate on the use of controls?  Why do we need this?  The racial and gender distribution is fairly similar over the 5 years we are looking at.

Comment: Ah, in that case it shouldn’t be so important unless you’re also comparing across zip codes as well. To partially answer the main question, usage of percentages shouldn’t pose any issue to making inferences about rates across your populations, especially since you have the total number of admissions, so you can get the counts of admissions in each population as well. You will probably need to provide more details on what you seek to understand to get more guidance on here.

Comment: I'm having trouble to think of a sensible hypothesis that could be tested with that kind of data. Is there any chance to investigate the absolute numbers of people within each zip-code? I assume that most hospital admissions will happen in zip codes with many people at risk and any analysis neglecting this strong effect is going to investigate mostly biases, like whether some ethnicities tend to live more in cities or more in rural areas.

Comment: Thanks Alex and Bernhard.  The zip code is available for a few states and we have race and sex distribution from US census data. Since we do not have denominator files we are using census data.  Can we make inferences like say 'Males in say state X have higher hospitalisation rates over time than Females' given that sex is not binary but recorded as a proportion for males?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simple answer is yes.  You *can* make inferences about the relationship of hospital admission rate to the *percentages* of races and genders in a zip code.  In other words, you can say that zip codes with a higher percentage of males have a higher hospitalization rate.  It is another inferential leap to say that males have a higher probability of hospitalization.  As a dump example, males in two zips might have the same intrinsic probability of hospitalization based on age and health, but when there are a higher percentage of males in a zip code, it leads to more contact sports injuries, and therefore more hospitalizations.  The unit of analysis is the zip code in this regression, not the people.

I think the comments on your question have highlighted some of the problems that may underlie your model and affect the interpretation.  It may also be that best predictor of the admission rate is the number of hospitals and the weather.  These regressions are difficult because those effects are included in the error when you don't control for them.
I suggest writing down the model you are going to fit for people to react to.  Something like this:

$ (Admission Rate_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 (white.perc_i) + \beta_2 (black.perc_i) + \beta_3 (Male.perc_i) + \beta_4 (Female.perc_i) + \epsilon $

If this is your model, then I'd suggest a couple of things:

1. Do not regress on the rate, use a population offset for the Poisson regression and use the log of the number of admissions
2. Consider the fact that the percentages are all correlated because they need to sum to one.  Maybe you can get away with only the white percent and male percent in the regression?
3. Consider interaction terms
4. It may or may not help to transform the percentages to the logit scale, you'll need to check the diagnostics.

It might also be that you know the percentage of the hospital admissions of each race as well as the percentage of the population of each race.  I couldn't tell from your question.

Example R code:

```r
set.seed(11001)

df <- data.frame(
  zip = 1:1000,
  pop = rpois(1000, 1000000),
  number_admission = rpois(1000, 10),
  percent_white = rbeta(1000, 2, 2),
  percent_male = rbeta(1000, 2, 2)
)
df$percent_black <- (1 - df$percent_white)*rbeta(1000, 2, 2)
df$percent_other <- with(df, 1 - percent_white - percent_black)
df$percent_female <- 1 - df$percent_male

lm1 <- glm(number_admission ~ offset(log(pop)) + percent_white + percent_male, 
           data = df, family=poisson(link="log"))
summary(lm1)
plot(lm1)

prediction_points <- data.frame(pop = rep(1000000, 9),
                                percent_white = seq(0.10, 0.9, by = 0.1), 
                                percent_male = seq(0.10, 0.9, by = 0.1))
plm1 <- predict(lm1, newdata = prediction_points, type = "response")

prediction_points$number_admitted <- plm1
prediction_points$admission_rate <- plm1 / prediction_points$pop
```

Comment: Beautifully explained and answered all my doubts!  Thanks R Carnell.  Thanks for the very helpful R code.  Much appreciated!!!